# Calculate A records dynamically

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns

I need a DNS server that essentially allows to resolve hostnames to any IP. For example, hostnames that look like `A-B-C-D.myhost.example.com` will be resolved to `A.B.C.D`. (of cource, A is 0-255 and so on. It's ok to return something useless for invalid hostnames)

I've seen that bind9 has `$GENERATE` directive, but it seems to be impossible to nest it (and 2^32 records would probably break the server or at least consume a lot of memory).

Is there any software that can do this? (probably something with support of regular expressions?)

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to achieve. What is the problem that you want the ability to dynamically create A records in bind?

Comment: There is other software that can do this, as an example PowerDNS has backends that can dynamically generate responses, like https://doc.powerdns.com/md/authoritative/backend-remote/

Comment: I don't see ***any*** practical use of having a subdomain that includes the IP address and the domain name.  It is very counter-intuitive as domain names are there to simplify the user's life, not to make it more complicated.  There could be cases where subdomains would be dynamic but not that way, and those are usually handled by the web server.

Comment: @user5870571, What I'm trying to do is to apply SSL certificate to all nodes that have the private key of that certificate. I could register the records when nodes are created, but this solution is more complicated and does not seem to provide any benefits.

Comment: @JuliePelletier, please see my comment above

Comment: Why don't you use a wildcard SSL certificate?

Comment: @user5870571, I do. Here is the issue: nodes are created dynamically and I only receive IP addresses of those nodes. Now I want to avoid creating DNS records for each node.

Comment: As @JuliePelletier stated that really doesn't (to me) make a lot of sense. Why not create FQDNs with the hostname of the host instead of the IP address?

Comment: @user5870571, I don't want to add an additional step. If I understand you correctly, each time the node is created I would have to register it with DNS server. This decreases the reliablity and increases development effort (it has to be done automatically). If the dns server would already be configured in a way that the node can be accessed via some name (user will never see it), it would eliminate this step.

Comment: @swat32.exe:  Why do you need each IP address to be linked to a DNS record if the users don't even see them?  Just use the IP directly in that case.

Comment: Note that anything can be automated but making it use a name chosen by the user would make much more sense and be actually easier to automate.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it is effectively a product recommendation question. You are looking for DNS software that implements record synthesis.

Comment: @AndrewB Could you give me an example of such product (I failed to find one that does what I want during a brief search)? Or is there a place where I can get such recommendation?

Comment: @JuliePelletier, I need to establish https connection to that IP, which I can't do without hostname (or self-signed certificate, which is not an option, since user will see a popup or connection will be just silently terminated)

Comment: @swat32.exe:  Like all hosting services, you create a DNS entry on the fly for username.hostingservice.com which will match your wildcard certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerDNS supports multiple backends, one of them is a pipe backend that you could use to process the query and send what you request. If you add the directives to use pipe (in this example I assume that you have some zone files, that's why the we `launch` the `bind` backend.

```
launch=bind,pipe
pipe-command=/etc/pdns/pdns-backend-ip.py
pipe-regex=^.*\.host\.example\.com;.*$
```

Then you can use a Python script `pdns-backend.py` to process the queries and send the results. Something like the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u

# Implementation of a Pipe Backend for PowerDNS
# https://doc.powerdns.com/md/authoritative/backend-pipe/

# We need Python unbuffered so we use -u
# Another ways to achieve it in 
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering

import sys

def build_answer(qname, qtype, answer, ttl=60):
        return("%s\tIN\t%s\t%d\t1\t%s" % (qname, qtype, ttl, answer))

def send_log(msg):
        sys.stdout.write("LOG\t%s\n" % msg)

def send_data(msg):
        sys.stdout.write("DATA\t%s\n" % msg)
        send_log("Sent %s" % msg)

# Check first line to ensure that we are properly initialized
line = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
if line != "HELO\t1":
        sys.stdout.write("FAIL\n")
        sys.exit(1)
sys.stdout.write("OK    Python backend is alive!\n")

# Process each line!
while True:
        raw_line = sys.stdin.readline()
        line = raw_line.rstrip()
        args = line.split("\t")
        if len(args) < 6:
                send_log("PowerDNS sent me unparseable line")
                sys.stdout.write("FAIL\n")
                continue
        rtype,qname,qclass,qtype,id,ip = args
        send_log("Received [[ %s ]]" % line)
        # PDNS will use the SOA to decide which backend to use. We have to answer only
        # when the query is as close as possible: 
        # i.e.: answer host.example.com not to example.com.
        if qtype == "SOA" and qname.endswith('host.example.com'):
            send_data(build_answer(qname, 'SOA', 'ns1.example.com ahu.example.com 2008080300 1800 3600 604800 3600'))
        if qtype in ("A", "ANY") and qname.endswith("host.example.com"):
                ip_requested = qname.split('.')[0]
                send_data(build_answer(qname, 'A', ip_requested.replace('-','.')))

        sys.stdout.write("END\n")
```

Having that DNS configuration would allow you to process that zone as dynamic:

```
$ host 11-22-33-44.host.example.com 127.0.0.1
Using domain server:
Name: 127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
Aliases: 

11-22-33-44.host.example.com has address 11.22.33.44
```

Maybe something like this is overkill and hard to debug (the sample python script does not do any error checking) but it could be a good starting point to having a really dynamic and programmable DNS server.